# Recovering windows partition in Mint (testdisk fails)

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, dual-boot, data-recovery

Yesterday I messed up my partitions, wanting to replace Ubuntu with Mint. My other partition had Windows 8 on it. I booted Mint from a live USB and started the Mint setup. I selected the option to overwrite Ubuntu with Mint. However before i clicked the Install button I changed my mind and thought it would be a good idea to make a backup of my windows partition. Unfortunately the damage was already done and I was unable to locate my Windows partition.

Gparted:

```
/dev/sda1 fat32           512.00 MiB      1.02 MiB        510.98 MiB     boot
/dev/sda2 ext4            224.50 GiB      7.69 GiB        216.80 GiB
/dev/sda3 linux-suspend     7.89 GiB      fs    ---               ---
```

fdisk:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   488397167   244198583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5 GB, 15504900096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1885 cylinders, total 30283008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc196969a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064    30283007    15137472    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I also tried testdisk but it tells me it couldn't recover any partitions and the ones that are listed are only a boot partition,linux's own partition or empty partitions/folders. Does anyone have any suggestions or have i just lost all my windows files?

[edit]

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="D435-92A0" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="0de14359-2f69-45ff-88a3-eefa41d127ad" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="f96fa82f-707f-41fe-bce1-cf61396f7869" TYPE="swsuspend" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UUI" UUID="8247-3FF1" TYPE="vfat" 
mint@mint ~ $ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 224.5G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0   7.9G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1  14.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.4G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   1.3G  1 loop /rofs
```

Comment: After booting your system with a liveCD can you mount and navigate any of these partitions? From the sound of it, it sounds like just the boot loader for Windows got trashed, but the partitions look to be in reasonably good shape.

Comment: @slm how do i know which partition to mount? My windows partition does not show up in any of the tables...

Comment: Do you have access to the commands `blkid` or `lsblk`? Do they show it?

Comment: Are you using efi with Windows 8?

Comment: see my edit in the OP. Can't find a NTFS partition...

Comment: Yeah that doesn't look good to me either. What does `efibootmgr` show?

Comment: `BootCurrent: 0008

Timeout: 2 seconds

BootOrder: 0008,0009,0007

Boot0007* CD/DVD Drive 

Boot0008* UEFI:  USB DISK 3.0 PMAP

Boot0009* Hard Drive 
`

Comment: So Boot0008, according to this is likely your Windows drive. This is just an entry in the efi firmware.

Comment: how do i access or recover it?

Comment: Boot0008 is my USB drive, the one i use to boot linux mint with. So i guess there is no way to recover my windows partition?

Comment: I don't see how if you cannot see the partition that it resides on with any tools.